# Create dynamic DataSource in web application

Tags: spring, datasource

I have a requirement to create dynamic DataSources on fly. Please allow me to explain what i did till now;

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db1"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>
```

In my controller (autowired instance for dataSource is available); what i did is;

```
    BasicDataSource newDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    newDataSource.setDriverClassName(request.getParameter("driverClassName"));
    newDataSource.setUrl(request.getParameter("url"));
    newDataSource.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
    newDataSource.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

try {
        dataSource.close();
        if(dataSource.isClosed()) {
            dataSource = null;
        dataSource = newDataSource;
        newDataSource = null;
    }

} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The surprising thing is; neither it does raise any exception nor it changes the dataSource.

I had made a go through on "AbstractRoutingDataSource" but i wanted to make as much as dynamic possible i mean...i wanted to connect  whole new database or even connect to other database (offcourse i will have the required jar files) on fly .

Please help :)

Comment: did you find any concrete solution for this ?

Comment: BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(newConnectionProperties)